# Print N number of observations that are non-missing from specific column in delimited file

Tags: awk, columns, output, gawk

Say I have `file.txt` that is pipe-delimited, and I want to take a look at 10 non-missing observations from the 20th column to ensure they appear in the correct format.

Would I use the `awk` command and how can I tell it only 10 observations?

`cut -d "|" -f 20 < file.txt|more` is helpful for completely non-missing columns but this doesn't help for sparse columns.

Comment: Could you please provide some lines of the input file and the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN {found=0} $20 && found<10 {print $20; found++}' /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cut -f 20 -d '|' file.txt | grep -v -e '^$' | head
```

and you can play with grep patterns to also remove spaces *'^[[:space:]]$'* if your file has entries like ..19|   |21..